# Output If statement on R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R shiny and am trying to make a diet calculator (assuming you have isotope values for 15N and 13C measurements for your fingernail/hair samples). I am having trouble formatting my if statement to produce my **output statement** that gives you a diet based on the d13C and d15N inputs (i.e., if values d15Nair = 6, d13Cpdb = -24...... **"your diet primarily consists of fruit, vegetables, and grain eaters")**.

It seems to me that this strictly a formatting issue, I would appreciate any feedback.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(numericInput(inputId = "Cnumber",
                             label = "d13C (per mil)",
                             value = "2",),
                numericInput(inputId = "Nnumber",
                             label = "d15N (per mil)",
                             value = "1"),
                textOutput(outputId = "DietCalculator")
)
             

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  d13Cpdb <- reactive(input$Cnumber)
  d15Nair <- reactive(input$Nnumber)
}
  if(d13Cpdb <= -23 & d13Cpdb >= -29 & d15Nair <= 7 & d15Nair >= -1)
  {print("Fruits, Vegetables, and Grain eaters")
  } else if(d13Cpdb <= -22 & d13Cpdb >= -29 & d15Nair <= 11 & d15Nair >= -7)
  {print("Non-corn-Fed Meat Consumers")
  } else if(d13Cpdb <= -17 & d13Cpdb >= -19 & d15Nair <= 6 & d15Nair >= 4)
  {print("Dairy Consumers")
  } else if(d13Cpdb <= -21 & d13Cpdb >= -18 & d15Nair <= 17 & d15Nair >= 12)
  {print("Marine Fish Consumers")
  } else if(d13Cpdb <= -12 & d13Cpdb >= -17 & d15Nair <= 11 & d15Nair >= 3)
  {print("Corn-Fed Meat Consumers")
  } else if(d13Cpdb <= -10 & d13Cpdb >= -13 & d15Nair <= 5 & d15Nair >= 3)
  {print("Corn & Sugar Cane Product Consumers, eat healthier")
  } else {(print("Diverse diets incorporating more than one source"))
  }
  output$DietCalculator <- renderText({input$Cnumber})
  output$DietCalculator <- renderText({input$Nnumber})
 
 
 
 
 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In `if (d13Cpdb <= -23 & d13Cpdb >= -29...)`, you need to specify `d13Cpdb` as `d13Cpdb()` as the reactives are functions.

Answer (score 0):

As @YBS mentioned, as `d13Cpdb` is a reactive, you need to change the code to be `d13Cpdb()`. The second thing I did was move the end bracket of `server<-function(input, output, session){ }` to encompass the `output$DietCalculator`. Also noteworthy that you have two different `renderText()` codes going to the same `output$DietCalculator`. If you wanted to display both, then you would need to make a second output of a different name, or perhaps if you wanted them both in one output, use a paste function, something like `paste0("Cnumber is ", input$Cnumber," and Nnumber is ", input$Nnumber)`. Lastly, I was thinking you wanted your if statement to display in the `renderText()`, so I moved that into the `renderText()`, and removed all of the `print()` functions. This way it would put it in the shiny app.  Hopefully this is about what you were looking for. Best of luck in your future endeavors!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(numericInput(inputId = "Cnumber",
                             label = "d13C (per mil)",
                             value = "2",),
                numericInput(inputId = "Nnumber",
                             label = "d15N (per mil)",
                             value = "1"),
                textOutput(outputId = "DietCalculator")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  d13Cpdb <- reactive(input$Cnumber)
  d15Nair <- reactive(input$Nnumber)
  
output$DietCalculator <- renderText({
  req(input$Cnumber, input$Nnumber)
  if(d13Cpdb() <= -23 & d13Cpdb() >= -29 & d15Nair() <= 7 & d15Nair() >= -1)
  {"Fruits, Vegetables, and Grain eaters"
  } else if(d13Cpdb() <= -22 & d13Cpdb() >= -29 & d15Nair() <= 11 & d15Nair() >= -7)
  {"Non-corn-Fed Meat Consumers"
  } else if(d13Cpdb() <= -17 & d13Cpdb() >= -19 & d15Nair() <= 6 & d15Nair() >= 4)
  {"Dairy Consumers"
  } else if(d13Cpdb() <= -21 & d13Cpdb() >= -18 & d15Nair() <= 17 & d15Nair() >= 12)
  {"Marine Fish Consumers"
  } else if(d13Cpdb() <= -12 & d13Cpdb() >= -17 & d15Nair() <= 11 & d15Nair() >= 3)
  {"Corn-Fed Meat Consumers"
  } else if(d13Cpdb() <= -10 & d13Cpdb() >= -13 & d15Nair() <= 5 & d15Nair() >= 3)
  {"Corn & Sugar Cane Product Consumers, eat healthier"
  } else {"Diverse diets incorporating more than one source"
  }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```